# How to create complex gradients in Figma?

Tags: patterns, css, figma

I would like to use [this CSS pattern](http://projects.verou.me/css3patterns/#carbon) in my Figma project but I stuck. So far, I have not found a description for implementing such a complex pattern.

Is this even possible in Figma? Or is it just embedding as an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, I don't think there's a way to use CSS3 code directly in Figma. Also, there's no automatic way of making custom pattern fills like more advanced vector software such as Illustrator/Inkscape.

However, you could create a similar pattern manually, using a few single rectangles with any fill or gradient you want. You could turn it into a component and duplicate, move and repeat.

An example

The component

[image]

Then build a wall by duplicating, moving and repeating the components

[image]

Since it's entirely made from one component duplicated, if you edit the original component, then all the other duplicates that make up the pattern will update automatically. This is handy if you need to edit/tweak the colours later.

[image]

If you want to use it as a fill for a shape, create a mask

[image]